# Error in DTM when created a new property and added new rule with javascript

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I have created a new property in DTM. Added header and footer code from DTM in the new website. I am using adobe's s_code version which i have set in the property. When I created a page load rule for custom tracking of the navigation it says "Uncaught Reference Error" s is not defined.

The page load rule that i have added is
//links tracking

```
$("a.top-nav-link").click(function() {       
    _satellite.notify('top nav clicked');
    var tophatlinks = "ntap:TH:" + $(this).text();          
        s.eVar14 = tophatlinks;
        s.linkTrackVars = "eVar14";  
        s.tl(this,'o');  
});
```

But If i use event based rule it works and doesn't give the error. Since I have to use many click events I thought of adding one page rule and add all the custom tracking there. But this is not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I made it work by adding custom s_code while updating the property. Adding s_account and commenting some unnecessary code it is working. Can any one let me know if this is the right way to fix this issue?

Comment: My first guess is you have have the default setup, so `s` isn't available in the global (window) scope for you to reference. There are several questions/answers on this site that are relevant. There's not a whole lot of traffic to adobe-analytics tag in general, so you should be able to find them easy enough just browsing the tag

Answer (score 0):

In DTM, `s` isn't a global variable so it cannot be directly referenced in some code fields.

However inside a rule, you can open the Adobe Analytics accordion and click 'custom page code' which open open a code editor where you can reference `s` without any issues.